# ILoadValueChangedEventArgs not fired in C#

Tags: c#

```
protected void ILoad1_ValueChanged(object sender, Radactive.WebControls.ILoad.ILoadValueChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        btnSelectImage.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/Originals/Temp/" + ILoad1.Value.SelectedImage.FileName;

    }
```

this event not fired in C#

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is probably you didn't register the handler to the corresponding event. You have `Handles ILoad1.ValueChanged` in the vb.net code(which seems bind the method to the event, I'm not familiar with vb.net), in c# you need to add something in the startup method.

```
ILoad1.ValueChanged += ILoad1_ValueChanged;
```

Comment: i added this code in page load, once add the image the value change event need to be fire but it is to fire btnSelectImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Radactive.WebControls.ILoad.AddImageAutoEdit('ILoad1'); return false;");

Comment: it is working on IE but it is not worked on mozilla. i forget to post this.